# NHibernate 3 compatible to SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, sql-server-2016

We have an application which is running on `NHibernate.3`. We have to migrate to **SQL Server 2016** but before doing it I need to know if `NHibernate 3` is compatible to **SQL Server 2016**?

We are using `MsSql2008Dialect` in `NHibernate` 3.

And our database and our code base is compatible to SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I would bet on my money that it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I've checked [Discontinued Database Engine Functionality in SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and I figured it out:

Discontinued Features in SQL Server 2016

1. SQL Server 2016 is a 64-bit application. 32-bit installation is discontinued, though some elements run as 32-bit components.
2. Compatibility level 90 is discontinued. For more information, see ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level (Transact-SQL).
3. ActiveX subsytem is discontinued. Use command line or PowerShell scripts instead.

And as I already said our application is totally compatible to SQL Server 2014. **I have tested and everything were working fine.**

Comment: We have just upgraded to SQL Server 2016 and are running NHibernate 3.3.  I immediately saw a drop in performance.  Does that mean I'm going to have to downgrade sql server to 2012 or 2014?

Comment: @jeffkenn I suggest you to profile your db queries with `SQL Profiler` to find the bottleneck.